# Exaggerating the peaks in a graph to a standard value

Tags: functions, terminology, graphing-functions

I will try to explain what I need, and I hope you can provide me some info about what this "procedure" is called so I can search further on the internet.

I have a plot with "peaks" that happen on "different" levels, something like this:
[image]

And I would like to know if there exists any function that can strengthen these peaks to the same level like the peaks on the right, so it would look something like this (made in paint sorry):
[image]

I am not sure it is it called normalisation or something like this, but please can you help me find the exact definitions or functions I should search for? I am using mathplotlib.

I want to strengthen the low "y" to the level of max "y", even though my plot will change completely.

The hardest thing is that I don't know what to search for, or if this even exists, I will appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Do you have the raw data? Do you have experience with coding? I don't know if there's a name for this and can't think of a reason I'd want to change only some of the data in this way, but it's probably a straightforward coding exercise to say "if this value is higher or lower than its neighbors by some threshold, replace it with the fixed value at the height of the red line instead".

Comment: I would probably call this something like "exaggerating the peaks in a graph to a standard value" in the question rather than the current title. "Strengthen" is kind of vague and "low y" is similarly unclear.

Comment: This is the result of my LSTM prediction model of BTC, peaks show a good spot to buy (theoretically). I have a function that detects peaks based on threshold value like 0.840. The problem is that value 0.840 will detect only the peaks on the right, and will ignore the peaks on the left, and I can't set threshold too low, because of peaks on the right. So I wonder if there is any way to strech the graph vertically in way that the larger  is y the less it gets streched and viceversa. It feels like I should convert values to <0,pi/2> and then pass through atan or something (tried and didnt work).

Comment: (tried and didnt work *or I made and error somewhere)

I have a coding experience but mostly backend + frontend, data science is new to me. Just trying to learn something new

btw. thanks for answer

Comment: This is maybe more programming advice than math, but rather than measuring a peak by exceeding a threshold absolute value, I'd say you should probably do something like "it the value at time $n$ is at least $x$ more (or $y$ times) the average of the values at, say, $n+3,n+4,n-3,n-4$. This is not meant to be the right specific values for your problem, but just to show an idea.